# DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems (first item to be blank and no duplicates)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms, append

I have a `DropDownList` inside an `UpdatePanel` that is populated on postback from a `SqlDataSource`. It has a parameter which is another control. I sometimes need multiple postbacks, but what happens is that each time the update panel refreshes, items are added to the `DropDownList`. So the `DropDownList` ends up having data that is incorrect, or repeated data.

I have the `AppendDataBoundItems` property set to `true` because I need the first item to be blank.

How can I overcome this problem? Is there another way to have a blank first item?

(This `DropDownList` is in an ASP.NET 2.0 web app, and codebehind is in C#)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Instead of using `AppendDataboundItems='true'` (which will cause the problem you are talking about), respond to the `DataBound` event for the `DropDownList` and then add your "blank" item to the top of the list.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="MyList"
  ondatabound="MyListDataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
protected void MyListDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select -", ""));
}
```

Comment: Am I the only person is having an issue with OnDataBound finding the method you have declared it to use? It doesn't appear to be looking in the back end of the code (Despite the fact the whole DropDownList is populated and created there.)

Comment: @Keltex: I wonder why, but it didn't work for me too. In debug, it doesn't hit the event at all.

Comment: sorry but in each post back my dropdownlist does not show the "select" string and in debug it does not enter to databound event. how can I solve that?

Answer (score 7):

There are good answers here but I felt the need to include more information because there are multiple options that work and we need to decide which to use.

First, we should understand `AppendDataBoundItems`. If `AppendDataBoundItems = "true"`, `ListItems` are added to the `DropDownList` without clearing out the old ones. Otherwise, the `DropDownList` is cleared about before the next `DataBind`. [MSDN AppendDataBoundItems doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems(v=vs.110).aspx)

There are basically 2 options covered by most of the answers:

**1. Define a blank option in html and add the ListItems from the database to the DropDownList only once.**

Notice 3 things here:

- Blank `ListItem` is defined in html
- `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`
- `DataBind` is NOT called on postbacks or when the `DropDownList` item
  count is > 1

Source:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="- Select One -" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyList.Items.Count <= 1 ) {
        MyList.DataSource = MyDataSource;
        MyList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Note: I like the logic of checking the count vs checking `IsPostBack`. Though PostBacks are often the cause of duplicate databinding, it is possible to cause it other ways. Checking the item count is basically just checking to see if it's already been loaded.

OR (option to use `IsPostBack` instead)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        MyList.DataSource = MyDataSource;
        MyList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**2. Clear and reload the DropDownList on each page refresh.**

Notice 3 differences from the first option:

- `AppendDataBoundItems="false"` (if it is not defined then `false` is it's
  default value)
- Blank `ListItem` is is added in code behind. We can't define it in html
  because with `AppendDataBoundItems="false"`, it would be cleared out.
- `DataBind` is called on every `Page_Load`

Source:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyList" runat="server" DataValueField="Id"  DataTextField="Name" 
    OnDataBound="MyList_DataBound" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MyList.DataSource = MyDataSource;
    MyList.DataBind();
}

protected void MyList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select One -", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably bind that DropDownList in the code behind. So you should not do it after postback again:

```
// probably in Page_Load method
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // do data binding here
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea, we can use 2 events: *DataBound* and *DataBinding*:

```
protected void MyListDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select -", ""));
}

protected void MyListDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyList.Items.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Clearing the list in MyListDataBinding function is effectively the same thing as setting AppendDataBoundItems="false".

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="state" DataValueField="state">
    <asp:ListItem Text="(Select a State)" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pubsConnectionString %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [state] FROM [authors]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Idea.

There's a property in the drop down list called `AutoPostBack` set it to true and then in the code behind you put all the binding method inside the `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`. That worked for me.

regards.