# Unable to sort data by price using DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to sort my data (which is in a datalist) by its price. Meaning that there is DropDownList for user to choose if they want the price from the most expensive to the cheapest and vice versa. The prices stored in my database is in random sequence according to my catID. I have written the code as follows but it did not sort accordingly to what i wrote. What have i done wrong here? Please advice me.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindDropDownList();
}

private void bindDropDownList()
{
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "price";
    DataList1.DataSourceID = null;
    DataList1.DataSource = getReader();
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

}

private SqlDataReader getReader()
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;

    if(DropDownList1.Text == "-Select-")
    {
      string strConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProBizConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText ="SELECT * FROM [Category ] WHERE catID<= 20";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        myConnect.Open();

   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Price - Highest to Lowest")
    {
        string strConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProBizConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "SELECT catID, packageName, price, description1, description2, image1, image2 FROM Category WHERE catID <= 20 ORDER BY price desc";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        myConnect.Open();

   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    }

    else if (DropDownList1.DataTextField == "Price - Lowest to Highest")
    {
        /string strConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProBizConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "SELECT catID, packageName, price, description1, description2, image1, image2 FROM Category WHERE catID <= 20 ORDER BY price";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        myConnect.Open();

   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    }
    return reader;
}
```

My .aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="18px" 
            Width="184px">
            <asp:ListItem>-Select-</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Price - Highest to Lowest</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Price - Lowest to Highest</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You might want to give more detail on the error... Did it not sort at all? Did it always sort low to high or high to low? did it not return anything? Are the names of the dropdown lists correct? You seem to be checking `DropDownList1` for the ordering information but that is also what you are trying to bind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  this line is wrong, might never evaluates to true

```
 else if (DropDownList1.DataTextField == "Price - Lowest to Highest")
```

should be

```
 else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Price - Lowest to Highest")
```

or even better

```
 else if (DropDownList1.Text == "Price - Lowest to Highest")
```

**Update:**

The `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` could be messing with your dropdown items. The results of Lowest and Highest are being merged may be that's why you couldn't see the difference.

Remove the default list items and put them in your code-behind

```
private void bindDropDownList()
{
   DropDownList1.DataTextField = "price";
   DropDownList1.DataSource = getReader();
   DropDownList1.DataBind();

   DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-"));
   DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Price - Highest to Lowest"));
   DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Price - Lowest to Highest"));
}
```

For alternative approach, check [DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems (first item to be blank and no duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730555/dropdownlist-appenddatabounditems-first-item-to-be-blank)

Comment: put a break point in your code and see what is going on - both in the if and else part

Comment: Now i know where the error lies. The output is that they sorted my price from highest to lowest and from lowest to highest and places them inside the dropdownlist instead of sorting it in my DataList as i uses the DataList to display the Products. So how do i sort the price by selecting from the dropdownlist and to display it in my datalist instead of selecting from dropdownlist and displaying it in my dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

The sort is not working on Price column correctly may be because the data type of Price is not a decimal and may be a Varchar

So please change the Price data type to Decimal to get the sorting correctly

Comment: I have changed the datatype to decimal but the prices still did not sort accordingly. It remain as the default layout whereby it is displayed accordingly to the catID.

Comment: Sure! I have added in my Question above.

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors that I can see...

1) Your `getReader` code has a path through it that returns null. You should probably make sure you always have an `else` for your default in case the other checks are false.

2) You are reading the value of `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` while trying to get the reader to databind to it. This looks wrong to me - I assume there are two dropdowns, one that has the ordering information and the other is what you are wanting to set and databind to...

3) In the elseif of the getReader you are comparing `DropDownList1.DataTextField` which should contain the name of the field you are binding (you set it to `"price"` earlier in the code in the `bindDropDownList` method.

If any of these errors are the problem you are encountering (and if they aren't now they probably will be in the future) then you should have been able to discover this just by stepping through in debug mode. That should tell you what paths the code is going down and so on.

If none of the above are causing your current problem then please give more detail. I've had to highlight three separate problems because your description didn't give enough to say what exactly had gone wrong for you.

http://tinyurl.com/so-hints is a very useful link to a page written to try to help explain what makes a question good and easily answerable.

Comment: The part that had gone wrong is that no matter what I've select in the dropdownlist (1. Price-Highest to Lowest 2.Price-Lowest to Highest) the output is still the same as the default (which is when user sees the page and that the data is displayed accordingly to the catID i have stored in my database).

Comment: And what about the other points I raised? Are you really binding the dropdownlist that has your price options to the result of your select statement? From what I can see the first time you run that code the most likely selected item is "-select-" (since none of them are specified selected by default I'd expect the first one to be) so I'd expect `getReader()` to return `null (since neither of the if stements matched). I'd thus expect it to try to databind with a null datasource... What is happening when you step through? Is this really the right code?

Comment: You're right! It return a null value as the first item is -Select-. However, i changed the codes accordingly to what codingbiz said whereby i deleted the list items and insert them in the .cs code. However, new problem arises. Now the prices did sort accordingly to the highest to lowest and vice versa but it sorted it in thr dropdownlist instead of sorting it in my datalist.

Comment: well as I said several times you are databinding that recordset to your dropdownlist - `DropDownList1.DataSource = getReader();`. Change that to whatever your datalist is called and it should be good... I sometimes feel like nobody reads what I write... ;-)

Comment: I changed it to DataList1.DataSource = getReader(); but i got the following error that says: "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DataList1'.  Remove one definition."

Comment: Is it meant to be using another datasource as defined by the DataSourceID? If not then remove that and you should be good.

Comment: And for what its worth you should be able to move back your dropdown list stuff into the aspx again if you want to. If you're not updating that dropdown any more than there is no need to do what codingbiz suggested in his answer.

Comment: I have removed the DataSourceID in my .aspx page but when i run my website, nothing appears at first. This is not what i wanted. By default, when user first sees the page, it should have the products that i displayed accordingly to my catID. And when users want to see the prices of the most expensive one, they can click on the option "Price - Highest to Lowest" in the DropDownList. Is there a way to keep both the DataSourceID (which is automatically created) and the DataSource (that is manually created in the .cs code)?

Comment: One would imagine you can remove teh datasourceid when you set the datasource. the other option would be to have you `getReader` method have an else statement that returns them in the default (catID) sort order and always run this to populate your datalist. This would also be useful for if in your dropdown people went back and chose "-Select-" in the dropdown which would currently return nothing (I believe).

Comment: Is that difficult to achieve? As my project is going to be due soon in 3 days time.

Comment: Nope. Just and in an else clause that looks just like the ordered ones but with your "default" sql in it and remove the if ispostback from your pageload to make sure it runs it every time.

Comment: I changes my code accordingly already but when i click the options in the dropdownlist, it is still the same as that of the default. I have Updated my codes above.