# Passing first values in drop down list when clicking search button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp Button and four drop down lists that are populated dynamically from a database.  When clicking the button, supposed to pass the selected values from the drop down list to a SQL stored procedure.  Instead the first value in each drop down list is being passed instead of the selected value.  Here is the code on the aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountry" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTypeStructure" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
 </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCategory" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSegment" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearhProjects" Text="Go" 
    CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnSearhProjects_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

And here is the C# code behind for the button:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindCountries();
            BindCategories();
            BindSegments();
            BindStructures();

        }



    }
public void SearchProjects()
    {
        Project project = new Project();
        string country = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
        string category = ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text;
        string segment = ddlSegment.SelectedItem.Text;
        string structure = ddlTypeStructure.SelectedItem.Text;
        List<Project> projectList = project.GetProjects(country, category, segment, structure);
        gvProjects.DataSource = projectList;
        gvProjects.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnSearhProjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchProjects();
    }
```

And this is how I am populating each drop down list:

```
public void BindCountries()
    {
        List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();
        Country country = new Country();
        countryList = country.GetCountries();

        ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryID";
        ddlCountry.DataSource = countryList;
        ddlCountry.DataBind();

    }
```

I have tried using `ddlCountry.SelectedValue.Text` and `ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value` and they do not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code in debug mode to make sure that the DropDownLists aren't being populated again after the postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.  I had an extra form tag on my master page with `method="post"`.  This was causing the page to post back to itself.  Once I removed the form tag, I was able to use the drop down lists properly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint (or some debug statement) in the `if (!IsPostBack)` code block on the `Page_Load` event to make sure it is not executing on the button click.

Also make sure the `value` attributes of your DropDownList ListItems are all unique, otherwise it will set it to the first duplicated value.

Comment: I have view state enabled on my page and for the control.  If I remove AppendDataBoundItems it is still passing the first value in each drop down list.

Comment: When I run the debugger and set a break point on `if(!IsPostBack)` it doesn't look like it is rebinding the controls (IsPostBack = true when running in Debug mode).  Also when I set `UseSubmitBehavior="True"` and click the submit button nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have any other code in the Page_Load method? Or any code in the Page_Init event method?

Comment: No I do not have any other code in the Page_Load method or Page_Init method.

Comment: Does it use a master page? Do you have any javascript on the page that could be causing the selected items to change? I'm trying to think of anything that could happen.. this is strange. When you click the button, all the options are still loaded in the list after postback?

Comment: Why would `UseSubmitBehavior="True"` make it so nothing happens? The `btnSearhProjects_Click()` doesn't get executed?? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Yes I am using a master page and there are some javascript functions that are making slide show of images.  When I click the submit button the items in each drop down list are being reloaded and the first value in each list is being passed (whether or not it is the selected item in the list) to a method that is running a stored procedure.

Comment: When `UseSubmitBehavior="True"` is present, clicking the button does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that page load has not run -- because these are dynamically created they are not set on postback.

You could also store  those values in the viewstate, but it seems you have turned viewstate off for the page.  (Viewstate *can* be a problem on dynamic pages, but then you need to get around this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this but I will get you give you a simple answer
try this and report back if this works
Autopostback set to false can cause this, viewstate being disabled can cause this as well

Store the values in ViewState or a Session variable or create a protected property if you like

assuming you are Binding the data,

There is DataBound event, which fires after data bounded to dropdown. As you are assigning dataSource to your dropwdwon and you need selected item after all the rows binded to dropdown

```
var selectedValue string.Empty;
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   selectedValue = ddlCountry.SelectedValue; // store it in some variable
}
```

You could also get at the ListItem of the DropDownList and use a foreach to see which Items are selected.. please make sure that you are doing this in the 
if (IsPostBack) of the Page_Load remember that the button click triggers a PostBack

```
foreach (ListItem item in ddlCountry.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        // TODO: Whatever you are doing with a selected item.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove AppendDataBoundItems="true".

[DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems (first item to be blank and no duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730555/dropdownlist-appenddatabounditems-first-item-to-be-blank)

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountry">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTypeStructure">
 </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCategory">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSegment">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearhProjects" Text="Go" 
    CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnSearhProjects_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```