# Ajax combobox with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit, vb.net-2010

i'm using a Combobox from AjaxControlToolkit in asp.net i'm filling this combobox with data from a database using sql Data Source, but i need to add an empty field in the combobox so in other words i need to add an empty row to the datatable but i'm using an sql data source so how can i do that ?

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

 <asp:ComboBox ID="service_listt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="CL_DESCRIPTION" DataValueField="CL_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="RedTypeComboBoxStyle" >
 </asp:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this question:

[DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems (first item to be blank and no duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730555/dropdownlist-appenddatabounditems-first-item-to-be-blank-and-no-duplicates)

Basically you could use `AppendDataDoundItems` property or use `OnDataBound` event to insert the empty value

Answer (score 1):

Change your Select command:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DemoConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand=
             "SELECT '' As [countryid], '' As [countryname] Union 
              SELECT [countryid], [countryname] FROM [Country]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```