# DropdownList listitems in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem

I want to have "Please select" on top of my dropdownlist, but when I feed the list items from the database the "please select" option is not displaying.

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="DropDownList3" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
    DataTextField="ROLENAME">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Please select"
        Value="" Disabled="disabled" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This was the solution for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730555/dropdownlist-appenddatabounditems-first-item-to-be-blank-and-no-duplicates]

Answer (score 2):

Add `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` to the DropDownList.

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="DropDownList3" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    DataTextField="ROLENAME">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Please select" Value="" Enabled="false" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And the correct syntax is `Enabled="false"`, not `Disabled="disabled"`. disabled=disabled is HTML code.

Comment: It didn't work for me, instead I tried ondatabound="DataBound"

Answer (score 0):

In .cs code, after DropDownList3.DataBind() insert a ListItem like this:

```
this.DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = "Please select", Value = string.Empty });
```

Comment: put code in code block in order to make it more readable