# How to make a dropdown have a blank value, but also not save all previously data bound values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have an ASP.Net web form. In this form I have three dropdowns:

`Site`
`Store`
`Aisle`

The `Site` dropdown is populated by an API call for an API that I created.

The `Store` dropdown is populated by an API call based off the value in the `Site` field.

The `Aisle` dropdown is populated by an API call based off of both `Store` and `Site` values.

In addition, I have a "blank" default value in each of these fields.

Currently, my `ASP` code looks more or less like this for each of the dropdowns:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropSite" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteDataSource" 
                      DataTextField="site" DataValueField="site" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text=" " Value ="" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The reason that I have `AppendDataBoundItems` set to `true` is because if I don't, then I'm unable to have a `blank` value in the dropdown (the databind replaces the blank value and it goes away).

However, let's look at a hypothetical: I pick `1` in my site field, and site 1 has stores of `a`, `b`, and `c`. `a`, `b`, and `c` populate as expected in the `store` dropdown. I change my `site` dropdown to `2`. Site 2 has stores `c`, `d`, and `e`. Because my `AppendDataBoundItems` is set to `true`, now my `stores` dropdown has values  (the blank value), `a`, `b`, `c`, `c` (again, since it's there from sites `1` and `2`), `d`, `e`.

Is there any way to force the field to refresh, but still have the blank value? I could add an entry to the database for the `site` that has a blank in `store`, and for each `store` that has a blank in `aisle`, but that seems like a lot of superfluous effort/bad design.

ETA: I'm willing to pursue a C# solution in the .aspx.cs web page if necessary, but all I can find is how to remove an item from a dropdown if you already know the value.

ETA: Code for data source per the comment (not sure how it's helpful, but here it is):

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetSite" TypeName="Test_Site_1.Controllers.SiteController"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Please share the code used to populate and return datasource.

Comment: @dj79 added the code. Not sure how it's helpful or relevant though.

Comment: every bit of information helps. In any case, this is not what I requested. I will clarify my request. Please share the SiteController code along with any code that is written for populating and returning the datasource.

Comment: This is however a duplicate question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730555/dropdownlist-appenddatabounditems-first-item-to-be-blank-and-no-duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems (first item to be blank and no duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730555/dropdownlist-appenddatabounditems-first-item-to-be-blank-and-no-duplicates)